# .htaccess redirect both http:// with and without www and https://www to https:// non-www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to redirect all of:

```
http://
http://www.
https://www.

to https://
```

This may have been answered here before, but having gone through the questions that seem relevant they are all not quite what I'm after, and everything I've tried resulted in a redirect loop or not working as hoped.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^energenie4u\.co\.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://energenie4u.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I was very close a couple of times... Thanks so much.

Comment: And, goodness help me, if I wanted to do the same, but point them all at the `https://www.`  ?

Comment: @PaulSkinner Just change the 2 instances of `energenie4u.co.uk` to `www.energenie4u.co.uk` (minding the `\` escapes)

Comment: I have done this yet it is not working for me... I prolly did something wrong, how can I troubleshoot? 
basically for me it still goes to www. although I set it up like how it is here suggested (apache2 ubuntu 14)