# .htaccess http to https with files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I am trying to program a redirect from http to https and also delete the www. It already does, my problem is that if you write: http://www.dominio.com/something/ should change to https://dominio.com/something/ and does not work, does not detect anything after .com anyone me help?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond% {HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ www.midominio.com 
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Https://midominio.com/$1 [R = 301, L] 

RewriteCond% {HTTPS}! = On 
RewriteRule ^ / (. *) Https:% {SERVER_NAME} // / $ 1 [R = 301, L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this question has been answered before here: [http to https through .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess)
and here
[.htaccess redirect both http:// with and without www and https://www to https:// non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687599/htaccess-redirect-both-http-with-and-without-www-and-https-www-to-https)

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work, in the others themes not exist the answer

    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond% {HTTPS} off 
    RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ www.midominio.com 
    RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Https://midominio.com/$1 [R = 301, L] 

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]